# Replacing GREP and AWK in Windows for Powershell

Tags: linux, windows, powershell, awk, grep

I have a linux command for a little video cutting library called ffmpeg.

I can use following command in Linux:

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -vn -i $1 -af "silencedetect=n=${THRESH}dB:d=${DURATION}" -f null - 2>&1 | grep "silence_end" | awk '{print $5 " " $8}' > silence.txt
```

Now i need to execute the exact same Kommand on a Windows machine via Powershell or CMD.

I am struggling with replacing the linux specific terms like grep and awk and the expressions they use.

Could someone please give me a proper replacement for this ?

Comment: Another possibility is to install WSL on your Windows system.  Probably overkill but an option none the less.

Comment: Install WSL is what i actually did to use this for now, as it comes handy to have the possibility to use a Linux shell in Windows and the powershell in general. 
But I also interested in a native windows solution. But thank you for this regardless.

Answer (score 0):

The replacement would be `Select-String` for both. The `grep` is a simple pattern match (`-Pattern -SimpleMatch`). The `awk` part just selects fields 5 and 8. You can use a regular expression pattern for that, just peek at the format produced. PowerShell sets `$Matches[]` to the various regex matches; `[0]` is the whole match while the other entries are for grouped sub-matches.